# Do loop is looping when I don't want it to in my 'game choices' program

Tags: c#

So I'm stuck again, I created a 'game choices' program that allows users to choose their 'skill' level. I have wrote all the code but the do loop on line 24 is causing issues. It will not loop when I choose a higher skill level than 4 or when I type 'n' in "Is this what you want (y/n)". Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name;
        int one = 1, two = 2, three = 3, four = 4;
        int answer;
        int tripalarm = 0;
        string verification;



        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(name + ", there are 4 skill levels in this game:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Advanced" + Environment.NewLine + "2. Experienced" + Environment.NewLine + "3. Average" 
            + Environment.NewLine + "4. Novice");

        do
        {
            answer = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Which skill level do you choose?");
            answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            if (answer >= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry " + name + " you should choose between 1 and 4:");
            }
            else if (answer <= 4)
            {
                if (answer == one)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you " + name + ", you have choosen level one");
                    Console.WriteLine("Is this what you want? (y/n)");
                    verification = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (verification == "y")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Good " + name + " you have chosen level one you can now start the game!");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        tripalarm++;
                    }
                }
                else if (answer == two)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you " + name + ", you have choosen level two");
                    Console.WriteLine("Is this what you want? (y/n)");
                    verification = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (verification == "y")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Good " + name + " you have chosen level two you can now start the game!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tripalarm++;
                    }
                }
                else if (answer == three)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you " + name + ", you have choosen level three");
                    Console.WriteLine("Is this what you want? (y/n)");
                    verification = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (verification == "y")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Good " + name + " you have chosen level three you can now start the game!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tripalarm++;
                    }
                }
                else if (answer == four)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you " + name + ", you have choosen level four");
                    Console.WriteLine("Is this what you want? (y/n)");
                    verification = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (verification == "y")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Good " + name + " you have chosen level four you can now start the game!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tripalarm++;
                    }
                }

            }

        } while (tripalarm == 0);



    }
}
```

I have tried almost everything, changing the while value at the bottom does not change anything. It still loops when it is not supposed to.

Much help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `I have tried almost everything`  was using the debugger something you tried?

Comment: Yes, it does not detected any errors.

Comment: I suggest using  a Switch statement rather than the else ifs

Comment: Yeah, thats not what the debugger does - it lets you watch the code and even interact with it as it executes so you can remove the bugs (hence the clever name *debug*)

Comment: Ok, gonna try that now, thanks.

Comment: I am literally new to the coding field I struggled to make this

Comment: Ok, how do I use the switch statement?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site - [switch (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) is amply documented and explained at MSDN which is easily accessed by pressing [F1]

Comment: As far as I can tell the loop should work for levels above 4 and won't work when you enter "n" as your if statements are the wrong way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simplifies your code a bit and should correct the bug:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var levelSelected = false;
    var answer = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");

    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"{name}, there are 4 skill levels in this game:");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Advanced");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Experienced");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Average");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Novice");

    while (!levelSelected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Which skill level do you choose?");
        answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (answer)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine($"Thank you {name}, you have choosen level {answer}");
                Console.WriteLine("Is this what you want? (y/n)");
                levelSelected = Console.ReadLine() == "y";
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine($"Sorry {name} you should choose between 1 and 4:");
                break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Good {name} you have chosen level {answer} you can now start the game!");         
    var x = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Note it still doesn't check that the user enters an integer for the level (if they don't it will cause an error) and anything other that "y" is treated as "n".

Comment: Thank you so much, I now understand how the switch function works.